# Creating a bold and indented title.

Tags: sectioning, indentation, bold, titlesec

Im working with an existing template and I need to make my sections bold and my subsections indented. I use the `titlesec` package.

My Section style is this

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Roman{section}.}{}{1em}{}
```

Which I need to be bold

And my subsection style is this

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\Roman{section}.\Roman{subsection}}{}{2em}{}
```

Which I need to indent (the roman numeral and the "title") 2em from the left margin

I have tried various different solutions for over an hour now but none of them seem to work... Could anyone help me out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)). Also, we usually don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I have correctly understood what you are trying to do (by the way, it would be good to include a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your questions so that it is easier to help you), the following code should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}} 
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\hspace{2em}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}\label{subsection1}

\subsection{Another subsection}
cf \ref{subsection1}

\end{document}
```

Here is the ouput:

[image]

Note that the `\titleformat` command is documented on page 4 of the `titlesec` manual (the `texdoc titlesec` command should open the documentation). The syntax is as follows:

```
\titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]{⟨format⟩}{⟨label⟩}{⟨sep⟩}{⟨before-code⟩}[⟨after-code⟩]
```

where `<command>` is the name of the sectioning command you need to customiz. `<sep>` is the separation between the label (in your case the roman numeral) and title, not between the left margin and the label. The `<format>` code allows you to specify the style applied to the whole heading (label+title). This is were you should put commands like `\bfseries`.

Edit: following @GonzaloMedina's comment, I have redefined the commands `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` to make sure that any `\ref` will produce the reference label in roman and not arabic numerals.

Comment: You are a LEGEND

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\hspace{2em}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} `. Otherwise, cross-references will still produce arabic numerals.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You are right, I have updated my answer to include your improvement.