# Getting chapter title bigger

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I would get bigger only the chapter title. I heard I should use `titlesec` package but I didn't understand how I should use it to achieve what I mean. I'm using `book` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it is difficult to give a precise answer, but here is an example of how to use `titlesec` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec,lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The command you are interested in is `\titleformat` and it has the following syntax:

```
\titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]{⟨format⟩}{⟨label⟩}{⟨sep⟩}{⟨before-code⟩}[⟨after-code⟩]
```

where the role of each argument is documented on page 4 of the `titlesec` manual (accessible by typing `texdoc titlesec` in a shell or [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)). Basically, you should put in `<format>` the formatting commands that should apply to both the label and chapter name, `<label>` is just how you want the label to appear (leaving blank would remove "Chapter 1" for instance), while `<before-code>` concerns the formatting commands that appear just before the chapter name. In my example, both the label and the chapter name are `\bfseries`, while the label is `\huge` and the chapter name is `\Huge`.

Note: you could also have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78772/creating-a-bold-and-indented-title/78775#78775).