Add indent in subsubsection header
I wish to add a fixed indent in every \subsubsection header in my thesis (only the title, not the content of the section).
I tried using the code explained in this question but i can't make it work: Creating a bold and indented title.
EDIT: I added the code \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{\hspace{1.5em}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{} and it works perfect. Thanks for nothing :)
Here's a simplified version of my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{geometry}     
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}   


\begin{document}
\section{Diseño y análisis}
\vspace{0.4cm}
Teniendo en consideración todos los requisitos y restricciones de los subsistemas y componentes, así como el diseño preliminar del LCT-23, se ha desarrollado el diseño optomecánico final. Para obtener el máximo rendimiento y mantener una alta fiabilidad, se han seleccionado componentes y materiales de primera clase.\\

El diseño se analiza en detalle en este capítulo, que se subdivide para describir cada componente principal, así como los diferentes análisis estructurales y térmicos realizados para comprobar el cumplimiento de los requerimientos establecidos. El capítulo se centra en el diseño optomecánico del cuerpo principal del terminal (banco óptico) y del sistema de apuntado fino (FSM), siguiendo la estructura del sistema observada en la Figura. \\



\subsection{Banco óptico}
\vspace{0.4cm}
\subsubsection{Diseño óptico}
El diseño incial del banco óptico que realizó XXX buscaba un diseño más compacto que los Keplerianos y los Galileo. Este diseño trabajaba con haces convergentes, lo que conlleva a diversos riesgos, como la necesidad de introducir varios divisores de haz y dicroicos en el sistema, lo que aumentaría la formación de astigmatismo. 
\end{document}



Which indent are you taling about? And why do you have \vspace{0.4cm} in your text? That is a clear indication that you are doing something wrong.

i want to add an indent to the header \subsubsection{Diseño óptico} so the number of the subsubsection starts at the same point that the first line of the paragraph below (i added an image to the question for better understanding)

I'm afraid your question has nothing to do with tocloft.

@Stephen okay i'm just a begginer i didn't wanna miss something important in the question

You have said that you tried the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78772/creating-a-bold-and-indented-title. Why doesn't it work? Where are you stuck?

BTW: Never use \\  at the end of a paragraph! → When to use \par and when \, \newline, or blank lines

@cabohah fixed! sorry. and i'll look into it
